# Drawing curve with canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, graphics, geometry, curve

I am working on a [specialized] graphics editor. It is used to draw simple vector graphics elements including arcs/curves.

We support a shape that mixes straight lines and curves. It gets drawn as a bunch of straight sections. At a later point, a designer can convert a straight segment into a curve. It looks like the below: [image]

We persist this object as an array of dots. Each dot has coordinates `x` and `y` as well as optional angles `r1` and `r2`. I draw the shape on canvas using the below:

```
        const parts = [ 
                      ...,
                      {x: 359, y: 187, r1: 0.4, r2: 0},
                      {x: 214, y: 184, r1: 0, r2: 0.5}
                      ...
        ];

        for (let j = 0, len = parts.length; j < len; j++) {
            const p1 = parts[j];
            const p2 = parts[j < len - 1 ? j + 1 : 0];
            if ('r1' in p && p.r1 > 0 && 'r2' in p2 && p2.r2 > 0) {
                console.log('point:', p1);
                console.log('next point:', p2);
                console.log('draw arc, angle:', p1['r1']);
                console.log('next vertex angle:', p2['r2']);
                ctx[j ? 'quadraticCurveTo' : 'moveTo'](p1.x + 50, p1.y + 50, p1.x, p1.y);
            } else {
                ctx[j ? 'lineTo' : 'moveTo'](p1.x, p1.y);
            }
        }
```

It works, I get straight lines and curves when I need them.

However, my control point is off. I temporarily coded it as `p1.x + 50, p1.y + 50` and this is not right. Knowing `p1` and `p2`, including coordinates and angles, how do I calculate the control point?

Comment: What do **two** angles r1 and r2 denote?

Comment: the input is not provided by API. meaning, that the editor will persist something like a sin/cos of an angle with each red line - ones between the control point and each of the curve's ends. however, for viewer, i need the way to calculate the intersection. i think that it should be something like: `x = (y1 - y2) + (tan r1 * x1 - tan r2 * x2) / ( tan r1 - tan r2)` and `y = (tan r1) * x + (y1 - (tan r1) * x1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to calculate intersection point of two rays. Using parametric representation:

```
      first ray              second ray
x = p1.x + t * cos(r1) = p2.x + u * cos(r2)
y = p1.y + t * sin(r1) = p1.y + u * sin(r2)
```

Solve this equation system (shortening variable names as p1.x=x1, cos(r2)=c2 etx )

```
x1 + t * c1 = x2 + u * c2 
y1 + t * s1 = y2 + u * s2 

t = (x2 - x1 + u * c2) / c1
y1 + (x2 - x1 + u * c2) / c1 * s1 = y2 + u * s2 
u  *  (c2 / c1 * s1 - s2) = (y2 - y1) -  (x2 - x1) / c1 * s1
u  *  (c2 * s1 - s2 * c1 ) = (y2 - y1) * c1 -  (x2 - x1) * s1

u = ((y2 - y1) * c1 -  (x2 - x1) * s1) / (c2 * s1 - s2 * c1 )
```

substitute this value into the first equations and get x,y of intersection

```
x = x2 + u * c2
y = y2 + u * s2
```

Zero value of denominator `(c2 * s1 - s2 * c1)` occurs for parallel vectors. Negative value of parameter `u` - for case of non-intersecting vectors when angle is too large. These cases are impossible when non-degenerate point sequence is used as input.